# Test for and remove substring in user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I want to create a batch file that echoes text that it receives as part of a user-inputted command.

```
@echo off
Echo execute a command
Set /p command=
if "%command%"=="echo 'some text'" goto echo
::my aim is to make "echo" ignored by System and Only read "'some text'"
:: like "set text_to_echo='some text' 
:echo
echo %text_to_echo%
```

Asking the user for the command first and then asking the user what to echo, like below, is not an option

```
@echo /p
set /p text=
if "%text%=="echo"
:echo
set /p tex1="Enter text to echo"
echo "%tex1%"
```

Comment: Is there some other reason to remove the command?  Otherwise you can just use the %command% variable directly to execute the echo.

Comment: I don't understand the wording of this, you want to be able to type a command and have it echo just the command excluding any leading `echo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
@echo off
Echo execute a command
Set /p "command="
if NOT "%command%"=="%command:echo =%" goto echo
pause
:echo
SET "text_to_echo=%command:~5%"
echo.%text_to_echo%
pause
```

Note that I also fixed your `if`, and put a `pause` after your `if` so you know whether it goes to `:echo` or not.

Comment: Might be better to substring the variable.  What if someone wanted to echo the words OFF or ON. The only way to do that is to have a character like the period or slash after the word echo. `echo\off` And if someone wanted to ECHO the word echo then it will echo nothing at all.

Comment: My thought was to just use a FOR /F and delimit on the space using TOKENS=1*.  That way the command would be in the first token and everything else would be in the second.  But of course that does not work if someone enters in `echo.Hello`.  This exercise can get a bit tricky.  Not sure why the person want to extract the command when all they have to do is put the command variable on a line by itself to execut the command.

Answer (score 0):

You want to split your Input into a first word (token) and the rest. You can do this with a `for`:

```
@echo off
Echo execute a command
Set /p "commandstring=# "
for /f "tokens=1,* delims= " %%a in ("%commandstring%") do (
  set "command=%%a"
  set "params=%%b"
)
if /i "%command%"=="echo" goto :_echo
...
:_echo
echo %params%
REM also possible (at least for "echo", but I guess, that's just an example):
%command% %params%
```